# Lista JSON no AngularJS não exibida

Tags: json, angularjs, web-service

Estou tentando retornar uma lista de um webservice Java, porém na página HTML ela fica em branco, não enxergo o meu erro, abaixo os código.

```js
@Path("/contatos")
public class ContatoResource {

  static private Map<Integer, Contato> contatosMap;

  static {
   contatosMap = new HashMap<Integer, Contato>();
   
   Contato b1 = new Contato();
   b1.setId(1);
   b1.setNome("Rodrigo");
   b1.setFone("9999-9999");

   contatosMap.put(b1.getId(), b1);

   Contato b2 = new Contato();
   b2.setId(2);
   b2.setNome("Ana");
   b2.setFone("8888-8888");

   contatosMap.put(b2.getId(), b2);
  }

  
  
  @GET
  @Produces("application/json")
  public List<Contato> getContatos() {
   return new ArrayList<Contato>(contatosMap.values());
  }
```

```js
var app = angular.module("listaTelefonica", []);
 app.controller("listaTelefonicaCtrl", function($scope,$http){
  $scope.titulo = "Lista Telefônica";
  $scope.contatos=[];

  $scope.operadoras=["oi","tim","vivo","claro"]
  $scope.adicionarContato=function(contato){
   $scope.contatos.push(angular.copy(contato));
   delete $scope.contato;
  }

  $scope.carregarContato = function () {
   $http.get("http://localhost:8080/AngularJS/rest/contatos").success(function (data) {
    $scope.contatos = data;
   });
  };

  $scope.carregarContato();
 })
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" ng-show="contatos.length>0">
   <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Nome</th>
    <th>Telefone</th>
    <th>Operadoras</th>
   </tr>
   <tr ng-repeat="contato in contatos" ng-class="{selecionado:contato.selecionado}">
    <td><input type="checkBox" ng-model="contato.selecionado" /></td>
    <td>{{contato.nome | uppercase}}</td>
    <td>{{contato.fone}}</td>
    <td>{{contato.operadora}}</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

O angular produz e consome objetos JSon em seus métodos http. Por isso, você precisa anotar na sua classe ContatoResource assim:

```
@Path("/contatos")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ContatoResource {
```